# Check URL and running function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Have a question regarding URL and jQuery or JavaScript.

How to running script if the domain bar equivalent with www.example.com ?

The script run if the domain bar equivalent with www.example.com and sub URL too, example www.example.com/suba, www.example.com/subb.

Can I specify URL to tell jQuery to run a function?

Sorry for my bad english :D

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with google?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with google. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Millions of tutorials about this online.

So you need to:

- 1 Check for the right URL: use `window.location.href` or another `window.location` property
- 2 Run the function if needed: `if(condition) functionName();`

This is what it should look like in the end:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('www.example.com') != -1) {
    // run script here
}
```

Comment: Maybe using `document.domain` instead. But i'm quite sure doesn't matter in OP's case

Comment: @A.Wolff He said he wants to check for "sub url" as well, I'm not sure if that means a subdomain (in which case your suggestion would work) or a sub-directory (in which case it wouldn't). Left it like this to keep it safe.

Comment: @Shomz != -1 what does it mean ???
I Am New about this (Jquery and Javascript). :)

Comment: You're welcome! [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) gives you a position of an item within its container. It's zero-based, so `"abc".indexOf('a')` would give you 0, `"abc".indexOf('b')` would give you 1, etc... However, if the match is not found, it returns -1. So what my code is doing is making sure that there is a match (opposite of being equal to -1). Makes sense?

Comment: @Shomz Oke thanks you so much for your help and your friendly answer :) , you make my mind clear :) your answer with friendly answer even this silly question. :D